# How to get count of affected row in T-SQL

Tags: sql, dynamicquery, rows-affected

I have an stored procedure with below body:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.sp_DeleteRoecords
    @Conditions NVARCHAR(200)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(2000) 

    SET @Query = 'DELETE FROM Customer Where ' + @Conditions
    EXEC (@Query)
END
```

How I can Get Affected Rows after executing the `@Query`?

Comment: You should hope no one types in `1 = 1` as a parameter to your query

Comment: look at the @@rowcount variable. I hope what you are doing in that stored procedure is not going into a production system.

Comment: Before your delete use a SELECT COUNT..WHERE.. into a variable

Comment: check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Comment: Do you really need the conditions variable? -Will you actually be changing the column your delete conditions are based on every time you run the script?

Is this part of an application? If so, can't you get the ID's of the records you want to delete based on logic in the back end, then pass this to the stored proc? Your code is VERY unsafe.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.sp_DeleteRoecords
    @Conditions NVARCHAR(200)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(2000) 

    SET @Query = 'DELETE FROM Customer Where ' + @Conditions + ';Select @@rowcount'
    EXEC (@Query)
END
```

Add Statement of @@rowcount after delete query.

Comment: Can you run `SET NOCOUNT OFF` before running this statement and try again? This query works for me on SQL2014.